# Durrett's Probability: Theory and Exmples Proof of Theorem 2.5.12

Tags: probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems

I'm having trouble understanding the end of the proof of this theorem. I will provide screenshots. It seems like they use Kronecker's lemma (Theorem 2.5.9) at the end but I do not quite understand it. Furthermore, I do not understand why there is a $p^{-1}$ factor in the estimate for $|\mu_m|.$

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The factor of $p^{-1}$ in the estimate for $|\mu_m|$ is spurious.
In the last argument, $X_i$ and $X$ should either both be $X_m$ or both be $X_1$.
At the end, the Stolz-Cesaro theorem [1] is implicitly used. It is just as easy to repeat its proof:

Write $$z_m:=E(|X_m|^p \, ; \, |X_m|>m^{1/p}) =E(|X_m|^p \, {\bf 1}_{\{|X_m|>m^{1/p}\}} ) \,.$$
Given $\epsilon>0$, dominated convergence implies that there exists $m_\epsilon$, such that $z_m<\epsilon$ for all $m \ge m_\epsilon$.
Then
$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \: n^{-1/p} \sum_{m=1}^n |\mu_m|   \le \limsup_{n \to \infty} \: n^{-1/p} \sum_{m=m_\epsilon}^n z_m m^{-1-{1/p}} $$ $$ \le \epsilon n^{-1/p} \sum_{m=m_\epsilon}^n   m^{-1-{1/p}}  \le C_p \epsilon\,.$$
Since $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrary, the $\limsup$ on the left equals zero.

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem

Comment: Do you have an intuitive explanation as to how we can bound the sum with C?

Comment: Are you asking about the last sum? We just compare the sum to an integral.